# HTML/CSS - Change Color of Padded Area

Tags: html, css

I have a content div with a white background and a footer with a gray background below it. The body background color is a lighter gray.

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content Div</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The footer has a top 2px border. My problem is that I want to change the background color below the border. Basically, I want about a 25px area directly below the border to match the body's background color.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1at9fs4m/)

So, I want it go white, light gray, border, light gray, dark gray.

Instead, it's currently going white, light gray, border, dark gray.

Is this possible?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You are explaining that in a complex way, post a screenshot/mockup of expected result instead.

Comment: You can use a background image in the fotter, 1px width, 25px height, in the desired color, repeated horizontally, placed at the top.

Comment: Have you considered using a horizontal rule, with margin, and setting it to dashed and the color you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the padding color but you can achieve this using `:after`:

```
.site-footer {
     /** Don't forget to add this property **/
     position: relative;
}

.site-footer:after {
    background-color: #F00;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catalinmunteanu/1at9fs4m/1/)

I've used red color so that you can clearly see where it is placed.

[MDN docs for :after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: Thanks it works, but when I put it live on my site instead of being positioned directly below my footer it is just positioned at the very top of the page.Any idea why this is ? If not it's ok, it'd be to difficult to post the entire site's code. You've got me on the right track.

Comment: Well you need to add `position: relative` to the `.site-footer`. It's written in the answer.

Comment: One problem is that when you change the background color to match body's color, the border doesn't display correctly. It appears to have a solid line going through it instead of being dotted.

Comment: That can't happen because of this new virtual element `:after`. I've updated the JSFiddle and set the border to 10px. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/catalinmunteanu/1at9fs4m/3/

Comment: You could zoom in your browser while viewing your webpage for a clear view. Use `Ctrl +` (zoom in),  `Ctrl -` (zoom out), `Ctrl 0` (reset)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could possibly use a `<hr />` tag for your line - I believe this would be easier, and just as semantic because it is a break between sections.

Alternatively, I had a similar idea to Catalin, but I used a pseudo border with the `:before`.

```
.site-footer {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 25px solid #EBEEEE;
  background-color: #818181;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

.site-footer:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  border-top: 2px dotted #999;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/qew9crx5/)